# Проблема переполнения C

Tags: c

Не могу разобраться в задаче для C:

1. Пользователь вводит целое положительное число k. Найти наибольшее значение суммы
   3^k +6^k +9^k + 12^k +... + (3n)^k
   которое не выходит за пределы диапазона типа long int. Определить значение n для найденной суммы.
2. Определить, какая операция является причиной переполнения при попытке вычисления значения суммы для n+1. Если причиной переполнения является суммирование слагаемых, то вывести символ «+» (плюс), если - умножение (при возведении в степень), то вывести символ «*» (звёздочка).
   В программе не следует использовать стандартную функцию возведения в степень, массивы и вычисления с плавающей точкой.

Значение n я нахожу, а вот со второй частью задания никак не могу разобраться. Показывает, что ответ неверный

Вот мой код

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    long int sum = 0, an=0, n=1, k, j;
    char symbol=' ';
    scanf("%ld", &k);

    while ((sum) <= (2147483647-an)){
        sum += an;
        an = 1;
        for (j = 1; j <= k; j++){
            an *= (n*3);
            if (an > (2147483647)){
                symbol = '*';
            }
        }
        
        n ++;
        
    }
    if (symbol != '*'){
        symbol = '+';
    }
    

    printf("%ld\n", sum);
    printf("%ld\n", n-2);
    printf("%c\n", symbol);

    return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода для k=3:
2143959867, 133, +

Буду очень благодарна за любую помощь

Comment: Возможное переполнение надо определять **до исполнения операции**, которая может его вызвать. Вот [тут](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow) есть функции для проверки, вызовет ли  операция с заданными операндами переполнение.

Comment: @avp да точно в условии не делала проверку, поэтому он, наверное, и выдавал неверные ответы. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

При при умножении разрядность всегда увеличивается!!!

```
long long int tt = an * n * 3;
if (tt > 2147483647) symbol = '*';
an = tt & 2147483647;
```

Comment: `long long int tt = an * n * 3;`. Т.к. переменные `an` и `n` имеют тип `long`, то вычисление произведения `an * n * 3` происходит в домене типа `long`, а не `long long`. Для 32-битного типа `long` проверка `tt > 2147483647` смысла не имеет. (Хотя, т.к. знаковое целочисленное переполнение вызывает неопределённое поведение, то нельзя исключать, что в каких-то случаях из-за хитрых оптимизаций компилятора такая проверка может сработать даже для 32-битного типа `long`, но полагаться на это не следует.)

Comment: Результат умножения очень сильно зависит от компилятора и архитектуры. Примерно 5% случаев будет 32бит результат - это когда железо не умеет 32бит*32бит=64бит. Очень очень древнее железо, или новое сверх дешёвое - из разряда 5 центов за чип.